# Are events that chain to jQuery Ajax functions simply fast-enough to register before the function call?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Suppose you write something like

```
$.post(file, options)
   .done(function(data){
       console.log('got data');
   })
   .fail(function(err){
      console.warn('error!');
   });
```

It is possible to chain each event in any order, and to omit either. So how then can it be assured the `done` and `fail` are in fact added to the event lists in time? If the `$.post` function completed its request instantaneously, would the events fire?

Comment: In your example, the functions in `done` and `fail` should be passed right away. But even if you do something like `var myDeferred = $.post(file, options)` and later on in the code write `myDeferred.done(function () {...})`, that function will still receive the results from the `$.post` call even if the call was already done before that. (sorry, it's late and I couldn't find a good source to link - this is from my past research)

Comment: What do you mean by "event"?

Comment: I just don't understand how `done` and `fail` can be chained to a function that is called immediately. The `$.post` function runs immediately, and returns something that allows `done` and `fail` to be chained. But my question is, what if the `$.post` function finishes instantaneously - would that  not mean `done` and `fail` had no chance to register? How is this design possible? Or is it just based on the known fact that an ajax request is never instantaneous?